# Using Anaconda modules outside of IPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, anaconda

I'm interested in creating physics simulations with Python so I decided to download Anaconda. Inside of an IPython notebook I can use the pylab module to plot functions, for example, with ease. However, if I try to import pylab in a script outside of IPython, it won't work; Python claims that the pylab module doesn't exist.

So how can I use Anaconda's modules outside of IPython?

Comment: you could just install the packages globally or use a virtulenv

Comment: pylab is only meant to be used interactively. If you're writing a script, you should use matplotlib directly.

Comment: @asmeurer: Still doesn't work if I use `import matplotlib`.

Answer (score 1):

I bet it will work if you use Anaconda's Python distribution.

Try running `./anaconda/bin/python` and importing it from that Python session.

Comment: you can run your script this way with `./anaconda/bin/python script.py`. Also of course you have to be in the right place in your directory structure :)

Comment: Hi G. Meyer, sorry for getting back to you so late. Unfortunately I am not sure that I understand your answer. (I'm pretty new with programming, so I take full responsibility for this). If I run python.exe from my Anaconda3 folder, then I get a command prompt where I can indeed do things like import pylab. However what I'm looking to do is run my scripts by, say, double-clicking on its icon (I'm using Windows 8 BTW). I think you tried to address this with your comment, but my Anaconda3 folder does not have a bin folder, or even a python script file...

Comment: ahh - sorry. firstly, I thought you were on a *nix system, not windows. But script.py in my answer above is simply a placeholder for whatever script you would want to run. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with developing in python on Windows so I can't help you out further. Perhaps adding `#!<replace this with the path to anaconda python.exe>` as the first line of your script would do it, but I really don't know.

Comment: On Windows you need to append to your PATH environment variable the directory of the python.exe in your Anaconda folder. If done correctly you should see details of the Anaconda distribution when typing 'python' into the command line

Answer (score 0):

As a side note,

If you want to keep this functionality and move to a more script-like environment I would suggest using something like Spyder IDE. It comes with an editor linked with the IPython console that supports all the same magics as the IPython notebook.